# Make sidebar scroll to the bottom when main reaches to the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a sticky sidebar which has a height of `calc(100vh-90px)` and main. Sidebar has some dynamic content so it will have scrollbar when the content is bigger than it's height. The main has many contents so it's very long. Is it possible to make sidebar scroll to the bottom when main reaches the footer? With sidebar `height: auto` it works but I want have the exact hight of the screen. Any leads on this would be appreciated.

The minimal html looks like this;

```
<nav></nav>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="sidebar></div>
</div>
<footer/>
```

and the css on the sidebar is;

```
position: sticky;
top: 90px;
height: calc(100vh-90px);
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: Add the minimal code needed to reproduce this

Comment: Good question! I’ve often wondered how to do something like this. It would be useful to see your code though.

Comment: Add  your layout code.

Comment: @aabdulahad  I have added the code and I know it's very minimal but something like this.

Comment: As of now, sidebar is unsrcollable becuase its height is less the viewport height. Where is the footer?

Comment: @mahan viewport is used to have the exact height of the screen. once height is set and if the content does not fit in the given height, does not it scroll?

Comment: Ifthe totale height of the content is more than the sidebar's height, content scrolls. But the sidebar does not.

Comment: @mahan I mean now the the sidebar is scrollable right? now the question is how would i make it scroll to the bottom when page reaches footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `footerInView` to detect the position of footer.

Move sidebar's scrollbar to bottom by `sidebar.scrollTop`.

```js
const footerInView = () => window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > document.querySelector('footer').offsetTop
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar')
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (footerInView()) sidebar.scrollTop = sidebar.scrollHeight
})
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.sidebar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 90px;
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div style="height:2000px;display: flex;align-items: end;">sidebar bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main" style="height: 2000px;"></div>
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```